# Values of keys in different arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, array-sum

So I have a query that returns the following results in PHP, and I'm trying to add the total of the `hours_played`, I have tried `array_sum()` but that does not seem to work, I would like to be able to add the values of `hours_played` to be 11 that way I can then pass that it another function :

```
Array
(
   [id] => 1
   [team_id] => 1
   [hours_played] => 1
)
Array
(
   [id] => 2
   [team_id] => 1
   [hours_played] => 4
)
Array
(
   [id] => 3
   [team_id] => 1
   [hours_played] => 6 
)
```

I'm a little bit lost and do I need to store the able Arrays in another array to be able to do this? The results above are from a sql query and is what is printed on the page when I `print_r` the `$row` variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE team_id = 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
   print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_*`?

Comment: Also, if you're not using the other columns then `SELECT SUM(hours_played) FROM table1 WHERE team_id = 1`

Answer (score 3):

You can either sum all the columns `hours_played` after having fetched the results and assigned them into an array, as shown below

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE team_id = 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
   $result[] = $row;
}

$sum = array_sum(array_column($result, "hours_played"));
echo $sum;
```

..or you can sum it up as you loop the results.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE team_id = 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$sum = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $sum += $row['hours_played'];
}

echo $sum;
```

Or, if you just need the total hours played, you can do that directly in one query, using `COUNT()` in MySQL.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(hours_played) as sum_hours_played FROM table1 WHERE team_id = 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['sum_hours_played'];
```

- [PHP `array_column()`](http://php.net/array-column)
- [PHP `array_sum()`](http://php.net/array-sum)
- [MySQL `COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)

---

**WARNING**
[**Do not use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? 
Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)
 - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which.

Comment: You have the parameters to `array_column` in the wrong order

Comment: That's what you get for writing code without testing it just before hitting the haysack. Thanks, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You're really close . You just need to add the 3rd index of each array together:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE team_id = 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$total = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
   $total += $row['hours_played'];
}
```

**CONVERSELY**  You can use the **numbered** index as well.

```
$total = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
   $total += $row[2]; // indexes start at 0
}

echo $total; // Will print 11 if your arrays you posted are correct.
```

**IN ADDITION --- WARNING!!** You need to be using `mysqli` instead of the far less secure and now **deprecated** `mysql`

Answer (score 1):

**Most Important**
[**Avoid using `mysql_*` functions**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are also officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
Read about using [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and change your existing code to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)

You can get a total of `hours_played` in the while loop. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE team_id = 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$total_hours_played = 0; // initialize a variable to get sum of hours
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
   $total_hours_played += $row['hours_played'];
}
echo $total_hours_played;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($array, 'hours_played'));
```

Comment: Might want to try harder, also add some description.